# Magmi Updating Product url_key

Tags: magento-1.8, import, url, csv, magmi

I'm looking to run a .csv dump file in magmi that updates the products url_key to ensure that all products keep their original key after a full export and import of products. (url_key may change due to name change after initial reindex therefore this is necessary to keep original paths to products in tact).

The issue I encounter is that if I run Magmi with my .csv file the url_keys don't update, that is unless I alter the url_key and save manually through magento admin. Then if I run magmi again only the products that I updated manually have their url_keys modified correctly.

Its a weird one but does anyone have any idea why the url_key wont update via Magmi unless I manually alter it in admin first?

Thanks.